# How to install mysql extension for php 5.3?

Tags: mysql, php, centos7, php53, extension

I'm trying to get an old application running under CentOS 7.8 which only supports php 5.3. I already compiled and installed php 5.3 but I'm not able to get the mysql extension working. Here is what I did so far:

1. installed php 5.3

   ```
   wget https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
   tar -xf php-5.3.29.tar.bz2
   cd php-5.3.29
   ./configure --prefix=$HOME --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysql=mysqlnd
   make clean
   make clean install
   ```
2. link to php-cgi

   ```
   cd ~/home/myuser/public_html/myapplication
   ln ~/bin/php-cgi php53.cgi
   ```
3. setup .htaccess

   ```
   Action     php53-cgi /php53.cgi
   AddHandler php53-cgi .php
   <FilesMatch \.php$> 
       SetHandler php53-cgi
   </FilesMatch>
   ```
4. install mysqlnd extension

   ```
   cd /php-5.3.29/ext/mysqlnd
   phpize
   ./configure --with-libdir=lib64 --prefix=$HOME
   make clean
   make clean install
   ```

mysqlnd.so extension was successfully installed to extension directory but when I load phpinfo.php it's not listed.

Comment: Did you edit the php config file to un-comment that line?

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I already added extension=mysqlnd.so to php.ini unfortunately without success.
I also tried to build php with configuration parameters --enable-mysqlnd=shared --with-mysqli=shared. This build the extensions and place them in extension_dir. But still not showing up in phpinfo.php